# Why does Rails show an ActionController::UnknownFormat when format is specified?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have code similar to the following, not much different than a scaffolded controller action for a Rails controller:

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
end
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
def create
  @user = User.new(first_name: params[:first_name]) # oops, I forgot the last_name!

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user) }
    end
    # do nothing if !@user.save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For a newb to Rails, this is could be a difficult problem to solve.  If you have multiple conditional paths in the `respond_to` block, you should ensure that you've considered all outcomes. If you do not provide an `else` branch as a fallback, then the `respond_to` block may be evaluated without encountering a `format.*` block, which Rails interprets as "format not specified."

The example code is a simplified version of actual code that I had encountered and struggled with identifying the cause of the error message.  As far as I knew, I had provided the format, `html`, but I was mistaken when I thought that my `format.html` block was reached inside the conditional.

I attempted to debug this code with Pry, only to find myself navigating the Rails source code, unable to determine why I was seeing the error.